# Custom work item control auto update in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have created a custom work item control for visual studio tfs work item. But the problem is whenever a team member wants to use the custom control they have to install and when the control is updated they have to reinstall the newer version. Is there any automatic update procedure or whether the work item controls loads from server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the Power Tools can help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2008/10/01/preview-of-the-next-tfs-power-tools-release.aspx (search for custom components). Requires the clients to set a checkbox in Team Explorer at "Team Members" -> "Personal Settings" -> "Install downloaded custom controls". But I don't know how far this will help your specific problem, please try it and report back.

At my company we built a program that checks versions of installed programs and compares them to the newest available one, independent of TFS.